# CSS hide all images with matching SRC attribute

Tags: css, css-selectors, wildcard

Is it possible to create a CSS rule that would apply a style to any IMG tag with a SRC that contained a specific string, say "hideme"?  For instance, if I had the following 3 images on a page it would hide the second one?

```
<img src="images/test1.png">
<img src="images/hideme.gif">
<img src="images/test3.jpg">
```

Comment: can you give more information on the situation you would use this?

Comment: This just became a "popular question" and I wish I remembered why I even wanted to do this :)

Comment: I believe this was a situation where I could not modify the HTML, but only "side-load" some CSS.  Based on the date, it may have been customization to CA Service Catalog.  FWIW.  ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 161, accepted):

Use this CSS3 [attribute selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#attribute-substrings):

```
img[src*="hideme"] {
    display: none;
}
```

I'd prefer to use a `hideme` class instead, but if you must hide an image based on its `src` attribute, the above is fine.

Comment: As usual, some versions of IE are known to have bugs with CSS3 attribute selectors. The SitePoint Reference is useful: http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/css3attributeselectors