# Hide image in the link when press link once

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I have the following script. All I want is, when I press on link once, then the image in the link disappears. The image I want to disappear after pressing the link is enter.png.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
 $(".open_close_doors").click(function(){
   $("#leftdoor_inner").animate({"left": "-=395px"}, "slow");
   $("#rightdoor_inner").animate({"left": "+=395px"}, "slow");

   setTimeout("window.location.href='wall.php';",200);
 });
});
</script>

<a class="open_close_doors" href="#"><img src='img/enter.png' onmouseover=this.src='img/enter_light.png' onmouseout=this.src='img/enter.png'></a>
```

Comment: What's the point? When you click the link, you're going to the wall.php page in 200 milliseconds, so the entire page is replaced and you won't notice the change of the image within that short time. Anyway, simply set the `src` to nothing `""` to make the image disappear.

Comment: any idea how to write this?

Comment: ok I see, thanks for the help... the reason i wanted the button to dissapear is because people sometimes continue pressing button unitl the redirection which takes a few seconds. thanks anyway

Comment: I already told you, set the `src` to nothing `""` to make the image disappear. So `this.children[0].src = ""`

Comment: or see this to select images with src you want `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6763899/css-hide-all-images-with-matching-src-attribute`

Comment: I see. Then you want the entire link to disappear, not only the image. This is easier, `this.style.visibility = 'hidden'`.

Comment: yes, i make the change to : <img src='img/enter.png'  onmouseover=this.src='img/enter_light.png' onmouseout=this.src='img/enter.png' this.style.visibility = 'hidden'> but the link is not dissaperaed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To hide the image, you can set its `src` property to nothing:

```
this.children[0].src = "";
```

However, since your goal is to prevent the user from clicking the button more than once, it is better to make the entire link disappear:

```
this.style.visibility = 'hidden';
```

Here is a demo (I commented out the redirection for demo purpose):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".open_close_doors").click(function() {
    $("#leftdoor_inner").animate({
      "left": "-=395px"
    }, "slow");
    $("#rightdoor_inner").animate({
      "left": "+=395px"
    }, "slow");
    this.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    //setTimeout("window.location.href='wall.php';", 200);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="open_close_doors" href="#"><img src='http://placehold.it/50x50' onmouseover="this.src='http://placehold.it/100x100'" onmouseout="this.src='http://placehold.it/50x50'"></a>
```